# Magento 2 Can't we use same name for ui_component file in different module

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I wanted to know, can we use same name for ui_component file.

Ex. In `\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\adminhtml\ui_component`  **product_listing.xml** is use to create product grid so can I use **product_listing.xml** in my custom module.

Ex. `app\code\<namespace>\<module>\view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_listing.xml`

I tried with above case but core one is loaded in place of my custom one.

How can I load my custom one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaking the names must be unique. If you use a similar name, Magento will squash both XML files down into a single configuration.

So if your module also has a `product_listing.xml`, it's content will be merged with the one that's also provided with Magento.

So yeah, use unique names.